# Using Timer with Progress Bar to open next form

Tags: c#, timer, progress-bar

It's very rough code, and im quite new at C# and I can't seam to know what is the problem with my code. It uses a timer and a progress bar. I know the code could be better though, and is a bit rough.. This is part of my first program and iv gotten very far.

My problem is when the progress bar is at 100% using the timer, the current room with the progress bar is supposed to hide, and switch to the next room. It works, but opens the next room twice? What am I doing wrong? I want the code to eventually do more stuff as it's loading as well, but not currently :).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
     public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
       public Form3()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         timer1.Enabled = true;
         timer1.Start();
         timer1.Interval = 1000;
         progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
         timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
      }

      private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      }

      private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (progressBar1.Value != 10)
         {
             progressBar1.Value++;
         }
        else
         {
             timer1.Stop();
             this.Hide();
             (new Form4()).Show();
         }
     }

     private void progressBar1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }
   }
}
```

It would be very nice if someone could help me with this bit of code! It would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subscribing to the `Tick` event in your code-behind.

Check to see if you've also subscribed to the same event in your `Designer.cs` file (you can check the "Properties" panel in the designer).

My guess is you've subscribed to the event twice, so everything in the event will happen twice, including creating and opening a new instance of `Form4`.

The solution would be to remove `timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);` from the `Form3_Load` event.